# Ruby require modules, libraries

Tags: ruby

I'm new to ruby. I understand that, when I see a ruby script, it usually contains lines similar to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubyfunction1'
require 'rubyfunction2'
```

I understand that the require lines are basically (to put it in simple basic terms), calling other scripts.  That is really all there is to it. These other scripts are functions.

Now, suppose, I put the content of the rubyfunction1 and rubyfunction2 scripts into two different variables. How do I require the content of a variable?

Or, suppose I want to be able to do something like this:

```
require '`/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb`'
```

I understand this is a roundabout way of requiring gems/ruby functions, but I'm curious to know if it is at all possible in this manner.

Basically, if I were to run the `/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb` script by itself on the command line, it will basically output to you the content of the script.  It would be equivalent to doing `"cat /home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb"`.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
require '`/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb`'
require '`/home/swenson/rubyfunction2.rb`'
```

or

```
specvar1 = `/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb`
specvar2 = `/home/swenson/rubyfunction2.rb`
require specvar1
require specvar2
```

Is this possible? Any suggestions I can apply to get it to work?

**UPDATE:**

So here's what I ended up doing.

Main Script called example.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

add = `./add.rb`     # for my purposes, this will serve as require
subtract = `./subtract.rb` # for my purposes, this will serve as require

eval add
puts "I can add: #{add(3, 2)}"

eval subtract
puts "I can now subtract #{subtract(3, 2)}"
```

Content of add.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts <<-function
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def add(a, b)
  a + b
end
function
```

Content of subtract.rb:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts <<-function
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def subtract(a, b)
  a - b
end
function
```

When run from the command line, I get no errors:

```
# ./example.rb
I can add: 5
I can now subtract 1
```

Basically, what I want done is precisely this.  However, I know there's probably a optimized way of doing this (without having to directly require the relative file).  So please, feel free to help me update or optimize this.

Comment: are you asking these awesome questions on the basis of your understanding of any other language? If yes mentioning that language would help us see from your perspective and future visitors too. :) welcome to Ruby Community.

Comment: yes, im coming from heavy shell programming background.  my boss feels my creativity can be put to better use with more modern languages...i.e. ruby, python. i chose ruby because i felt drawn to it.  it looks like a language i can master in about a month or two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think I understand your question correctly, let's say we have 3 files

**add.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

def add(a, b)
  a + b
end
```

**subtract.rb**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "def subtract(a, b)"
puts "  a - b"
puts "end"
```

**example.rb**

```
require './add.rb'
subtract = `./subtract.rb`

puts "I can add: #{add(3, 2)}"

# can't do `subtract`, yet, as we haven't `eval`ed the code even though we've run executed the file

eval subtract

puts "I can now subtract #{subtract(3, 2)}"
```

And the output of running `ruby example.rb` on the command line is:

```
$ ruby example.rb 
I can add: 5
I can now subtract 1
```

So, **add.rb** just defines a function `add`. When we `require` that file, it gets loaded in so we can use that function in our code with no problems.

But, **subtract.rb** doesn't define a function...it just outputs some code, so running it on the command line looks like:

```
$ ./subtract.rb 
def subtract(a, b)
  a - b
end
```

So now, in our third file **example.rb**, we `require` the **add.rb** and then we can start using `add` in our code as is, but then we want to execute the **subtract.rb** (using back ticks here) and capture the output of it. At this point, we can't `subtract` 2 numbers, because we haven't done anything with the output. Then we use `eval` to evaluate the output of the `subtract` method, which will define a method for us, then we can `subtract` the 2 numbers without a problem.

Note that `eval` is generally frowned upon because it allows arbitrary code to be executed. Never `eval` untrusted code unless you know how to tame it. In this case, as @JörgWMittag has pointed out in the comments, this code should be trusted, otherwise you just executed an un-trusted file to get this code. Be careful with user input, though, as that's not trusted.

Comment: using complex constructs like `<<-` and `rescue` to explain simplex of a method like `require` is not wise I suppose. It might confuse the questioner. Is it possible to simplify the explanation?

Comment: "Note that `eval` is generally frowned upon because it allows arbitrary code to be executed. Never `eval` untrusted code unless you know how to tame it." – Although, in this case, you are `eval`ing the output of a file you have already executed, so either the file is trusted, or you have already run untrusted code anyway.

Comment: Good points to both, I'll simplify that example and yeah, you've already executed the file, so in this case the code is trusted. That was more aimed as a "Don't just start `eval`ing strings from users willy nilly" @JörgWMittag

Comment: @SimpleLime  thank you for agreeing to simplify your answer.  in the example.rb script (i presume this is the main script thats calling the other scripts?), i want the require command to basically run the script i pass to it.  and when it runs the script, the script will print out/spit out its content, which is considered an output.  similar to what you have in subtract.rb script.  it is this output I want to require.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that with `require` you would have to set it up similar to how I did the `subtract.rb` file. Where you run it and save the output to a variable `subtract = \`./subtract.rb\`` and then you execute the output via `eval subtract` and that runs the code that was output by the previous script and saved into the string variable (in this example, it ends up defining the `subtract` method)

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that the require lines are basically (to put it in simple basic terms), calling other scripts. That is really all there is to it.

Yes. `load`, `require`, and `require_relative` simply run a Ruby file. That's it.

> These other scripts are functions.

No. They are scripts. There is no such thing as a function in Ruby.

> Now, suppose, I put the content of the rubyfunction1 and rubyfunction2 scripts into two different variables. How do I require the content of a variable?

You can't. `require` runs a file. It takes the name of a file (more precisely, a relative path) as an argument. Ruby code is not the name of a file.

> Or, suppose i want to be able to do something like this:
>
> ```
> require '`/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb`'
> ```
>
> I understand this is a roundabout way of requiring gems/ruby functions, but im curious to know if it is at all possible in this manner.

This is possible. There's nothing special about this. It will simply run a file at the path `` `/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb` ``. That is a slightly unusual path, but there is nothing special about it. It's just a path like any other, with some funny characters in it.

> so to iterate what im trying to do, i want to be able to do something like this:
>
> ```
> require '`/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb`'
> require '`/home/swenson/rubyfunction2.rb`'
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> specvar1 = `/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb`
> specvar2 = `/home/swenson/rubyfunction2.rb`
> require specvar1
> require specvar2
> ```
>
> Is this possible? Any suggestions I can apply to get it to work?

It's not quite clear what you want here. Those two code snippets are in no way equivalent, they do completely different things!

The first one passes the literal strings `` '`/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb`' `` and `` '`/home/swenson/rubyfunction2.rb`' `` as arguments to `require`. The second one *executes*  two files named `/home/swenson/rubyfunction1.rb` and `/home/swenson/rubyfunction2.rb` using the default system shell (`CMD.EXE` on Windows, `/bin/sh` on POSIX), gets the standard output as `String` and passes those strings to `require`.

Note that in the *first* case, the backticks `` ` `` are part of the filename, whereas in the second case, they are Ruby syntax for calling the `` Kernel#` `` method.

Comment: the second one is what I want to do.  i basically want to be able to require an output (to put in simple terms).    i want ruby to use the default system shell to run the script i give it, which will produce an output. and the output produced is what I want to require.  based on the responses I've seen so far in this thread, im feeling quite optimistic that it may be possible :)

Comment: It is still unclear to me what you want to do. You say, you want to "`require` the output of running the file". But, you `require` **paths**, and your files don't output paths, they output **code**. So, you simply *cannot* `require` the output of your files. This smells like an [*X-Y problem*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/2988) to me: you have problem X, and you *think* the solution is Y, but you run into a problem implementing Y, and now you are asking about your problem with implementing Y, instead of how to solve your problem X.